# calculating a gps coordinate given a point, bearing and distance

Tags: python, gps, coordinates, bearing

I have a problem which draws my back in some project for some time now.

I'm basically looking to trap a polygon using x, y points drawn by some script I've written.
lat, lon are the center GPS cords of the polygon and I'm looking for its surrounding polygon.

here is a part of my code in python:

```
def getcords(lat, lon, dr, bearing):
    lat2=asin(sin(lat)*cos(dr)+cos(lat)*sin(dr)*cos(bearing))
    lon2=lon+atan2(sin(bearing)*sin(dr)*cos(lat),cos(dr)-sin(lat)*sin(lat2))
    return [lat2,lon2]
```

my input goes like this:

- lat, lon - are given in decimal degrees.
- dr - is the angular computed by dividing the distance in miles by the earth's -radius(=3958.82)
- bearing - between 0-360 degrees.

However for the input:

```
getcorsds1(42.189275, -76.85823, 0.5/3958.82, 30)
```

I get output:  `[-1.3485899508698462, -76.8576637627568]`, however `[42.2516666666667, -76.8097222222222]` is the right answer.

as for the angular distance, I calculate it simply by dividing the distance in miles by the earth's radius(=3958.82).

anybody?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use [nice libraries](http://code.google.com/p/geopy/)?

```
from geopy import Point
from geopy.distance import distance, VincentyDistance

# given: lat1, lon1, bearing, distMiles
lat2, lon2 = VincentyDistance(miles=distMiles).destination(Point(lat1, lon1), bearing)
```

For lat1, lon1, distMiles, bearing = 42.189275,-76.85823, 0.5, 30 it returns 42.1955489, -76.853359.

Comment: I have tried to apply this solution in QGIS for points in EPSG:4326 but the result is not the proper one, it seems there is  problem with the bearing, for example when I try bearing = 0 the new point is located in ~90º Any clue about the potential problem? I am using PyQGIS to create the layers

Comment: **Don't use `geopy`!** It's no longer maintained and [have become problematic](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/pull/144).

Comment: Is it not maintained?  Many new versions since this answer.  This syntax does not work with the current version (1.20.0).  Point is no longer needed, Vincenty is deprectated, and a tuple with lat, long, and altitude is returned  This works: 
`lat2,lon2,_ = distance(miles=distMiles).destination((lat1, lon1), bearing)`

Comment: Is there a default we can use for 'bearing'?

Comment: @Brendan - it doesn't make sense to have a default bearing, as you would then get lat/lon coordinates offset in an arbitrary direction; that's like saying to stand at one point on earth, walk a certain distance, then tell me your new position, without indicating what direction you should have walked. This answer has bearings along each N/S/E/W axis though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40645383/181509

Answer (score 5):

With [geopy v2.0.0](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) (+ kilometers instead miles)

```
from geopy import Point                                                                                                                                                                       
from geopy.distance import geodesic                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                              
distKm = 1                                                                                                                                                                                    
lat1 = 35.68096477080332                                                                                                                                                                      
lon1 = 139.76720809936523                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                              
print('center', lat1, lon1)                                                                                                                                                                   
print('north', geodesic(kilometers=distKm).destination(Point(lat1, lon1), 0).format_decimal())                                                                                                
print('east', geodesic(kilometers=distKm).destination(Point(lat1, lon1), 90).format_decimal())                                                                                                
print('south', geodesic(kilometers=distKm).destination(Point(lat1, lon1), 180).format_decimal())                                                                                              
print('west', geodesic(kilometers=distKm).destination(Point(lat1, lon1), 270).format_decimal())
```

result is

```
center 35.6809647708 139.767208099
north 35.6899775841, 139.767208099
east 35.680964264, 139.778254714
south 35.6719519439, 139.767208099
west 35.680964264, 139.756161485
```

Comment: **Don't use `geopy`!** It's no longer maintained and [have become problematic](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/pull/144).

Comment: @not2qubit That issues was resolved. Is there further evidence that we should stay clear of it?

Comment: For a better understanding, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48485675/1147688).

Comment: geopy had a [release](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/#history) six weeks ago, and eight last year. It would seem that sometime after @not2qubit 's comment, someone picked it up.

Comment: I'm glad that someone tries to maintain their own code base, but unfortunately some of the most basic info/documentation is still missing from the repo. With the result that the common user have no idea what they are calculating and how.

Comment: @not2qubit I updated the example above, with geodesics. I only did a quick test (starting at 0°N and °E) and moving 111km, and it seems to deliver plausible results.

Answer (score 3):

The sin and cos functions expect their arguments in **radians**, not in degrees. The asin and atan2 functions produce a result in **radians**, not in degrees. In general, one needs to convert input angles (lat1, lon1 and bearing) from degrees to radians using `math.radians()` and convert output angles (lat2 and lon2) from radians to degrees using `math.degrees()`.

Note that your code has two other problems:

(1) It doesn't allow for travel across the 180-degrees meridian of longitude; you need to constrain your answer such that -180 <= longitude_degrees <= +180.

(2) If you are going to use this function extensively, you might like to remove the redundant calculations: sin(lat1), cos(dr), cos(lat1), and sin(dr) are each calculated twice.