# Get New GPS with Known start GPS, bearing and distance in feet

Tags: python, geopy

I am brand new to Python in general and have a limited but aged knowledge of Javascript. I am trying to accomplish a small project using Python, but I have gotten stuck with my own comprehension.

I have a GPS coordinate in decimal degrees as a starting point (30.456025341663068, -86.41408883615411), a distance **in feet** (86 feet) from the start point to the expected endpoint and I have a bearing in degrees (0 to 360) from start point to endpoint. Given these values, I am attempting to simply return the GPS coordinate in decimal degrees of the endpoint.

I found one StackExchange post that appears to give me a viable option using GeoPy, but I'm simply getting lost in trying to implement it. Can someone assist with how to accomplish this? GeoPy is not a requirement for me, I just imported it based on the answer in the other StackExchange question:

[calculating a gps coordinate given a point, bearing and distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530943/calculating-a-gps-coordinate-given-a-point-bearing-and-distance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
import geopy
import geopy.distance

lat = 30.456025341663068
lon = -86.41408883615411
distance_ft = 86
bearing = 0

start_point = geopy.Point(lat, lon)
end_point = geopy.distance.geodesic(feet=distance_ft).destination(start_point, bearing)

print(end_point.latitude, end_point.longitude)
```

This should output something like:

```
30.456261790886277 -86.41408883615411
```

You can then also use the geodesic method to calculate the distance between the points:

```
print(geopy.distance.geodesic(start_point, end_point).feet)
```

And get something like:

```
86.0000000020017
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured it out about 30 seconds ago, but my discovery is identical to yours, so props to you and thanks for the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer which is not using geopy

```
from pyproj import Geod
g = Geod(ellps="WGS84")

lat = 30.456025341663068
long = -86.41408883615411
```

```
feet_in_meters = .3048
distance_in_feet = 86
distance_in_meters = distance_in_feet * feet_in_meters
```

```
long_destination, lat_destination, azi_back = g.fwd(lons=long, lats=lat, az=0, dist=distance_in_meters)
```

which `print(lat_destination, long_destination)`

```
30.456261790886273 -86.41408883615411
```

Comment: This answer ignores the bearing.

Comment: It is in the arguments, az=0, short for azimuth

Comment: azimuth is not bearing

Comment: yes - it is not the same